# "No data available in table" shows even after datatable loads

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm facing a trouble in JQUERY Datatable Angular 4. I initialized the DataTable for a table which binds in the init event of the component.

DataTable initializes and shows 10-15 rows and pagination, filter and everything shows including the sorting. But even after that under the bottom of the table it says **No data available in table** and **Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries**
[image]
I didn't understand the reason

This is the function

```
loadUserList(): void {
    this.waitMessage = this.waitMessageLoadList;

    this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/User').subscribe(result => {
        this.userLists = result.json() as userList[];
        $('#tbl_userlist').DataTable();

    }
        , error => { console.error(error); }
        , () => {
            this.waitMessage = "";

        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in view

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#dataTableId').DataTable();
        });
    }, 0);
```

Comment: It is unclear how this code snippet is an answer to the question.